# How can I unzip multiple "7z" files all in one go, and have the contents go into a respective folder with the same name as the zip file?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, fedora-24

As the title says, I would like to know how to be able to unzip multiple "7z" files at once, and have the contents of the .7z files placed in a folder (in the same directory as the ".7z") with the same name as the .7z file. Also, is it possible to automatically create the folders if they don't exist?

Comment: Best and working solution can be found in below link - https://superuser.com/questions/371384/extract-all-zips-in-a-directory-incl-subfolders-with-a-bat-file-or-dos-comm/371581#371581?newreg=bcf9321f6ec34563a26396cba4388ccf

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there is a commandline option so you will have to use some kind of loop. An example could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.7z do
    dirName=${i/\.7z/}
    mkdir "$dirName"
    7za x -o"$dirName" $i
done
```

Comment: Quote the `"$dirname"` else it will do mess in case of spaces... `;-)`... maybe better `for i in *.7z` to avoid to parse ls ( [trdr;](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/66388) other problems with newlines and special characters.)

Comment: But who would use spaces on a linux system! You're right ofc.

Comment: It's full of people that persist to use windows out there... `:-D` and that continue to send you files...