# Windows 10 batch unzip multiple files with filename the same as zip directory name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, zip, 7-zip

I have about 60 files to unzip as you can see below:

[image]

know the 7zip option, which can unzip all of them, but the problem is, that the file inside doesn't match the zip directory name, which would be highly desirable here.

I found some solutions for the batch file here:

[Extract all Zip's in a directory (incl. subfolders) with a .bat file or dos command](https://superuser.com/questions/371384/extract-all-zips-in-a-directory-incl-subfolders-with-a-bat-file-or-dos-comm)

and prepared some batch code for this which looks like this:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 cd /d %~dp0
 for %%a in (*.zip) do (
  Call :UnZipFile "C:\my\Desktop current\Occ KMZ\bat\Aldebaran" "C:\my\Desktop current\Occ 
  KMZ\bat\Aldebaran"
  )
   exit /b
```

but it doesn't work at all. I can neither unzip it nor get files.

The 7zip software has a few options, which potentially could be good

[image]

I found also some options here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967931/renaming-files-to-folder-names

[How can I unzip multiple "7z" files all in one go, and have the contents go into a respective folder with the same name as the zip file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1134806/how-can-i-unzip-multiple-7z-files-all-in-one-go-and-have-the-contents-go-into)

but they didn't work either.

How can I solve this problem?

but I don't know how to use the 7Zip command line in order to get the unzipped file with the same name as the zip directory.

What should I do to automatize this section?

Comment: Where is the function `:UnZipFile` defined. Did you mean to use `UnZipFile` (no `:`)?

Comment: Yes, but even if I remove the colon ":" there is no reaction at all.

Comment: So where is `UnZipFile` defined? Is it a program? Another batch file?

Comment: I want to unzip all directories from the path provided, which you can see next to the Unzip function

Comment: <sigh> You haven't answered my question. You are trying to `call` a program called `UnZipFile`. Where is this program?

Comment: I have 7Zip I have no UnZipFile program. Alternatively, I could do it via batch file powershell command.

Comment: I don't think I understand: Are you trying to rename a file or folder inside the Zip? If so, unzip everything, rename and zip up again.

Comment: I would like to batch unzip these folders and rename files inside them at once. For example, if I unzip  2045-10-10 I would like to have the filename 2045-10-10.kml inside. Is it possible?